# Leaving one zone manually open

Tags: hvac

I just installed a new P5 Pure Pro trio oil boiler heating system replacement of old 27 year old system, and with the new system I converted to zone values from 5 circulators now I have one circulator, total of 5 zones one being for hot water with Amtrol 60 water heater for my hot water supply.  My first floor is always cool and calling for heat, so I have an idea like to try, manually open that first floor zone (always open) so antytime the other 4 thermostats call for heat, the first will also get heat also since the entire system is on one circulator, I welcome pros and cons?? Any any draw backs to do that from the heat system? Cost more? Use more oil or less oil?

Comment: If it's always calling for heat anyways then what's the benefit of leaving it open manually?

Comment: Because the first floor does not have enough baseboard and if I close the zone, it seems to run most of the day and uses more fuel... So by opening the zone, its running the heat on the first floor when another zone say on the seconds floor calls for heat.

Comment: Also, when the first floor thermostat normally calls for heat it runs like it normally does but the zone is already opened manually of course.

Comment: Also, I was hoping since the other zones don't run as long, and benefiting by heating the first floor at random times, I would use less oil.

Comment: Solve the actual problem:  install more baseboard in the first zone.  Kludge solutions only lead to trouble and/or waste down the line.  Further, why would you want heat in your first floor every time the zone for your hot water came on?

Comment: Hi Carl - thanks for the note, sadly I really don't have much more area available to install baseboard, I would have to go to a Multipak 80 and rip out Fireline 30.

Comment: As far as the hot water, my wife and daughter use it alot, and it runs quite often, and why not circulate the heat on the first floor while its heating the hot water?  The run time to keep the hot water hot seems to be the same to me whether the valve is open or closed on the first floor.

Comment: I see you work at Autoliv, I use to work in Lowell at the same location at Scheidt & Bachmann.  I know Autoliv is a great company and growing!  Met a few of the guys there who went to the gym and played soccer/Frisbee football outside.